# Can not view MP4 output files in HTML

Tags: rendering, video

As a learning exercise I am trying to use Blender's video editing capability to modify a mp4 file. The problem is that my rendered output can be played using VLC, Dragon, and gnome-mplayer but it won't play when using an HTML <video> element.

To be specific, I am starting with a copy of [Sita Sings the Blues in H.264/MPEG4 format](https://archive.org/download/Sita_Sings_the_Blues/Sita_Sings_the_Blues_large.mp4). I've clipped out ~ 15 seconds, added a fade-in effect strip at the beginning and also deleted the audio track. The result is an 18 second video which I then try to render and output as an mp4 file. I have tried a variety of output and encoding settings but the result is always the same: I can play it back perfectly in any of my standalone players but dropping it into a browser wont work. Firefox gives me a "File is corrupt" message and Chrome just sits there and does nothing.

BTW, I can generate AVI and MOV files that Firefox will play without complaint. Its only MP4 that is an issue. Unfortunately, I need to be able to play mp4 files in a browser for my intended application.

Has anybody seen this type of problem before or have any suggestions?

Thanks

Larry

Comment: Could you post your HTML so we can double check it?

Comment: I'm not sure if mp4 is supported anymore by html5 video

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with manualy: I convert the MP4 with VLC to MP4. :) This is a rough solution but works.